# Why doesn't the walrus operator increment my index

Tags: python

```
aTuple = (100, 101, 102, 103)

for aBool in (False, True):
    index = -1

    if aBool:
        print (aTuple [(index := index + 1)])
        print (aTuple [(index := index + 1)])

    print (aTuple [(index := index + 1)])
    print (aTuple [index])
    print ()

'''
Expected output:

100
101

100
101
102
102


True output:

100
100

100
101
102
102
'''
```

Coming from C++, I expected a post-increment.
But as @chepner pointed out, index is incremented in advance.
Oops...

Comment: *Why* did you expect that output? `100 101` and `102 102` are inconsistent.

Comment: @chepner made clear my mistake, thanks.

Comment: Note that if it *was* post-increment, your first call to `print` in either case would use `aTuple[-1]`, which is 103.

Comment: Yes, have been debugging for a bit to long, time for coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does increment `index`; but the value of the expression is the new value of `index`

`print(aTuple[(index:=index + 1)])` has the same effect as

```
index = index + 1
print(aTuple[index])
```

so at the end of the loop, the two `print` functions see the same argument.

--

As an example of avoiding explicit index manipulation, you can use a slice with a dynamically selected starting point:

```
aTuple = (100, 101, 102, 103)

for aBool in (False, True):
    for x in aTuple[:3 if aBool else 1]:
        print(x)
    print()
```

Comment: So if it assigns index = index + 1,  why does it print 100 twice if the aBool is false?

Comment: Because its the *last* two lines that print those. The first one increments `index`, then uses the new value of 0. The second one uses the current value of 0 again.

Comment: The same thing happens when `aBool` is True, except it's the index of 2 that gets repeated.

Comment: I see, you're right!

Comment: As an aside, try not to use `:=` like this, as an equivalent to prefix `++`.

Comment: Just having some C++ blues... But it seems I'd better not, thanks!

Comment: There are usually higher-level abstractions available in Python than explicit index manipulation for traversing sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting `index` to -1 at the beginning of the `for` loop. It *did* successfully increment the first time (100 was printed, not 103 as you would expect if it hadn't been - clearly, the print statements are executed with `index == 0`, not `index == -1`, which could only have been because of the assignment operator in the first print statement), but then you reset it the next time. So, incremented once is 100, incremented again is 101, etc.

Remove that assignment, and keep the one outside the for loop, and you'll get the `IndexError` you're expecting, as the index climbs higher than 3.

Comment: Sorry I put in the extra assignment, I've edited it out, but the problem seems to stay.